# Python Pandas : Unable to assign the list value using df.loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to assign the list value at specific index and column of dataframe, whereas unable to get the required result.

```
df:
  mac  location
0 1    lab
1 2    conference


for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.loc[index,"location"] = [row['location']]
```

The above one returns as string whereas the actual response I am suppose to get is,

```
df:
  mac  location
0 1    ['lab']
1 2    ['conference']
```

Comment: your commands run correctly on my system. It returns `[lab]` and `[conference]`. They are lists of string. Pandas output representation doesn't show the single quote of string `lab` , and `conference` inside list. However, if you run `df.at[0, 'location']`, it will show `['lab']`

Comment: If return the type as string for row['location']

Comment: how do you check it? you check it inside of for-loop?

Comment: Naively, something like `df['location'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.split())` works?

Comment: @Andy L, The given iteration in the description works fine. Its was a very silly mistake. I was executing different file for the same process. Now everything works fine. Thank You.